# prototype update method to COPY vs MOVE

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

i am using prototypes update method.  what i notice is that when it updates the receiving element with the providing elements innerHtml, the providing elements innerHtml is removed.  not only the innerHtml, but the entire element.

is it possible to retain both the element AND the innerHtml?

so basically i just want to COPY the innerHtml to the other element, instead of essentially MOVING the entire element.

is there a prototype function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a prototype function for
>   this?

```
$('targetelement').update($('copyelement').clone());
```